Sharepoint external links audit
Good afternoon!
I have a task to create a PowerShell code to check all shared links from our SharePoint site, regardless of when they were created. The current limit is 180 days. Is it possible to use PowerShell to check for the entire period?
We need to close links that were shared more than 180 days ago.
Also, is it possible to also include the links created when a Guest user is invited to a MS Teams team (so granting also access to the Files tab)?
Thank you.
